# Easy Soldering to Aluminum?

Tags: soldering

I am building an antenna with aluminum elements.

Is there any easy way to solder copper wire to the aluminum? I do not need a very strong connection, just a good electrical connection so I can then apply glue etc.

I tried sanding the aluminum and applying cooking oil, but that didn't seem to work. I will try motor oil later, but I don't think that will be any different.

The aluminum is a 1/4 inch rod.

I got it to work on aluminum foil, but it won't work on the rod for some reason?

[Would something like this work?](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30-ml-Highly-active-liquid-flux-for-soldering-aluminum-fast-delivery-/271380861662?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f2f8f52de)

Comment: Soldering to aluminum is very difficult under the best circumstances. The rod is probably too large a mass to solder to; consider welding a chunk of copper to it and soldering to that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Soldering to aluminum](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/soldering-to-aluminum)

Comment: maybe I will just find another way to attach the copper without soldering

Answer (score 5):

One well-known solution is to use a piece of polyvinylchloride tube as flux when soldering. It's better to solder with a slightly overheated soldering iron this way. Then resolder the same connection with some neutral flux.

I don't know the exact chemistry of this method, but it worked for me to solder aluminium wires (but not thin foil). It's better to do it in a well-ventilated place.

Comment: I would guess that the chemistry is Al2O3 + (carbon, chlorine) = CO + 2AlCl3 The aluminium chloride sublimes at  182C. Having discovered that it is basically impossible to solder to aluminium with regular solder/flux, I am very curious about this, and despite the toxic fumes, will probably try it out.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I've seen several times on both DIY and smaller commercial antennas is using a combination of screws and washers or solder lugs to attach the feed to the antenna elements. Here's one idea from [Homemade 14 element Yagi antenna for PMR446](http://fucimin.altervista.org/en/yagi14el.html) that would be pretty easy to put together:

[image]

Comment: Mechanical connections are the best solution short of welding. A thin copper tube just barely wider than the aluminum antenna tube, pushed on then crimped would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Between the time you sand it and apply the oil, it oxidizes again.  If you're going to have a chance, you would have to apply the oil and then sand with the oil in place.  This still does not make it easy.